# Better way to reduce a sorted list of numbers by merging values in close proximity?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of numbers with following values as an example.

```
2, 99, 101, 150, 198, 201, 300
```

We assume the above array will always be sorted in an ascending order.

My goal is to average out values which are in proximity to each other defined by a variable `x`.
Assuming `x = 5` the expected result should look like following

```
2, 100, 150, 200, 300
```

Following is a working copy of code I came up with

```
import statistics
def mean_reduce_by_proximity(data, distance):
    new_data = []
    temp = []
    for val in data:
        # if temp list is empty
        if (len(temp) == 0):
            temp.append(val)
        # if temp list if not empty
        else:
            # Last item of temp list is in proximity to current value
            if (val - temp[-1]) <= distance:
                temp.append(val)
            # Not in proximity
            else:
                temp_mean = round(statistics.mean(temp))
                new_data.extend([temp_mean])
                temp = []
                temp.append(val)

    # Handle last set of item(s)
    if (len(temp) > 0):
        temp_mean = round(statistics.mean(temp))
        new_data.extend([temp_mean])
        temp = []

    return new_data

In[1]: mean_reduce_by_proximity([2, 99, 101, 150, 198, 201, 300], 5)
Out[1]: [2, 100, 150, 200, 300]
```

My queries

- Is there a known technical term for this type of reduction?
- Is there a built in function in any of the popular python libraries that does
  this?

Comment: What would be the expected result for this: `2, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 150, 198, 201, 300`

Comment: @SayandipDutta The posted working approach in the question gives `[2.0, 102.0, 150.0, 200.0, 300.0]`, so I would assume the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
def mean_reduce_by_proximity_vectorized(a, thresh):
    # Get an array with indices off input array, such that each index
    # represent start of a group of close proximity elements
    i = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,np.diff(a)>thresh,True])

    # Sum based on those indices. Hence, each group is summed.
    sums = np.add.reduceat(a,i[:-1])

    # Get counts of each group
    counts = np.diff(i)

    # Get average of each group and round those for final o/p
    return np.round(sums/counts.astype(float))
```

Sample run -

```
In [90]: a
Out[90]: array([  2,  99, 101, 150, 198, 201, 300])

In [91]: mean_reduce_by_proximity_vectorized(a, thresh=5)
Out[91]: array([  2., 100., 150., 200., 300.])
```

Comment: @PrathameshGharat If this answer has answered your question, don't forget to accept it. More info on how to do so, etc. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Thanks for the vectorized form @Divakar!
I'll try to execute it step by step to figure out how it works.
If you could, please add comments to any place where you feel it would be necessary for python beginners.

Comment: @PrathameshGharat Added comments. To have a better understanding, it would be better to run each step and study output from it.